# Parsing HTML page: difference in page content between Java code and browser

Tags: java, html

`URL`: https://www.bing.com/search?q=vevo+USIV30300367

If I `View source` of the above URL (in Internet Explorer 11 for that matter), the sub-string pertaining to the first search result is:

`"[h2][a href="https://www.vevo.com/watch/rush/tom-sawyer-(live-exit-stage-left-version)/USIV30300367" h="ID=SERP,5075.1"]Tom [strong]Sawyer (Live Exit Stage Left Version[/strong]) - Rush - [strong]Vevo[/strong][/a][/h2]"`

Whereas via Java code, I `get` this:

`"[h2][a href="https://www.vevo.com/watch/rush/tom-sawyer-(live-exit-stage-left-version)/USIV30300367" h="ID=SERP,5077.1"][span dir="ltr"]Tom [strong]Sawyer (Live Exit Stage Left Version[/strong]) - …[/span][/a][/h2]"`

The formatting is a bit different (check the `[span]` tags), but even worse, the video title has been truncated in the search result string (i.e. `"Rush - Vevo"` became `"..."`).

Why is that? How to fix it?

(NOTE: I am using "[" and "]" in this post as replacements for the original HTML tagging delimiters to avoid my strings being formatted here on SO.)

Below is my Java code:

```
private String getWebPage(String pageURL, UserAgentBrowser uab)
{
    URL url = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    URLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder pagedata = new StringBuilder();
    String contenttype = null, charset = "utf-8";
    String line = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(pageURL);
        conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", uab.toString());

        contenttype = conn.getContentType();
        int indexL = contenttype.indexOf("charset=") + 8;
        if (indexL > 7) {
            int indexR = contenttype.indexOf(";", indexL);
            charset = (indexR == -1 ? contenttype.substring(indexL): contenttype.substring(indexL, indexR));
        }

        is = conn.getInputStream(); // Could throw an IOException
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));
        while (true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;
            pagedata.append(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
         // mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         // ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Nothing to see here
        }
    }

    return (pagedata.length() == 0 ? null : pagedata.toString());
}
```

And

```
String pagedata = getWebPage("https://www.bing.com/search?q=vevo+USIV30300367", UserAgentBrowser.INTERNET_EXPLORER);
```

Where `UserAgentBrowser.INTERNET_EXPLORER.toString()` equals:

`"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"`

Comment: I also tried this user-agent string `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0a2) Gecko/20110613 Firefox/6.0a2` with the same result.